# Python SMTP Authentication error when sending email through Outlook only when password is provided

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, exchange-server, smtplib

I am trying to use the generic python SMTP lib modules for sending an email from an outlook web application (not office 365) through Python. I am using the right host server name and port no. But still, I am unsure why I am receiving an authentication error. I understand that this is a frequently asked question, but I still wonder why it is unable to authenticate. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Our email is configured with a DUO set-up (Two-factor authentication). I initially assumed this might be the reason. But the other methods I used worked perfectly fine without doing any additional setups
Some methods I tried were.

- Using Python's win32com.client module in Python for sending email
  through Desktop Outlook App.
- Using Powershell to send an email

The code is pretty straight forward and simple.

```
import smtplib
from getpass import getpass

email = '********'
password =getpass("Enter your password")

with smtplib.SMTP('xxxx.xxx.xxx',25) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login(email,password)
    subject = 'Test'
    body = 'Testing email'
    msg = f'Subject:{subject}\n\n{body}'
    smtp.sendmail(email,email,msg)
```

It always shows this error, irrespective of the ports I am using.

*raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')*

**EDIT:**
*Ok!! so the code absolutely runs fine if I remove the login and prompt password statement. But this seems to be dangerous and I am not sure why it's allowing us to send emails even though we are not logged in. Maybe the Windows Server Active Directory is already registered on the domain*